# Correct words to differentiate between two different types of rechargeable battery longevity

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

A rechargeable battery has two different types of longevity:

1. How long the battery will last for a specific application.  For example, the duration of time that the battery, when charged, can be used to operate your smartphone until it runs out of power.
2. How long the battery will be a viable battery.  For example, the duration of time from new that it takes for your battery to no longer be able to effectively hold a charge.

Both of these terms refer to *rechargeable battery longevity*, but the definition of the word *longevity* is not sufficiently narrow for the reader to ***immediately*** understand the meaning.

What words can be used for each case to ***concisely*** inform the user of the intended meanings?

Comment: I'm stuck at 'overall/working life' and 'single-charge life'.

Comment: 2) The life time of the battery. In 1) it is not the time the battery lasts, but the charge  it holds. You might refer to its **capacity** which makes it obvious that you are not talking of its longevity.

Comment: One variable is the ***capacity*** (generally measured in ***[milli]watt-hours***), the other is the [***self-discharge***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-discharge) rate. The latter is generally measured as some ***percentage*** reduction in capacity per day / week / month for today's Lithium-based rechargeable batteries, or per ***year*** for non-rechargeables (where ***shelf life*** is also relevant terminology).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about chemistry and electronics, not English.

Answer (score 1):

One charge:

> **capacity**: the amount of physical charge, *Q*, that an element, such as a battery, can deliver at a stated voltage. generally represented in the form of *A•h*.

> **discharge cycle**: the process of discharging once

> **discharge time**: the amount of time required to complete a discharge cycle, which varies depending on the amount of current, *I(t)*, drawn on average, as well as *Q*.

> **C-rate**: an industry-standard metric of quantifying how much steady-state current, *I*, is required to discharge a battery with a given capacity in 1 hr

> Q = I(t)•t, assuming steady current during the entire discharge cycle, this simplifies to Q = I•t

All charges:

> **life cycle** or **cycling life**; **lifespan**:  1. the cumulative amount of discharge time over all discharge cycles until the product has reached the end of its usefulness life; 2. the cumulative number of discharge cycles until the same

> "During charge, lithium gravitates to the graphite anode (negative electrode) and the voltage potential changes. Removing the lithium again during discharge does not reset the battery fully. A film consisting of lithium atoms forms on the surface of the anode called solid electrolyte interface (SEI). Composed of lithium oxide and lithium carbonate, the SEI layer grows as the battery cycles. The film gets thicker and eventually forms a barrier that obstructs interaction with graphite." source: [link](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/what_causes_lithium_ion_to_die#:%7E:text=During%20charge%2C%20lithium%20gravitates%20to,and%20the%20voltage%20potential%20changes.&text=Dahn%20stresses%20that%20a%20voltage,the%20worse%20the%20degradation%20gets.)